# Azure.Data.Tables method - how to change from using shared key + Uri to managed Id?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-managed-identity

I have an Azure function (HTTP Trigger) that writes to a queue, but also to a storage table.
It's been working fine but now I need to move everything over to use managed identities.

I was able to change the HTTP trigger to use a __serviceUri env variable to connect instead of using a connection string.  But now I need to figure out how to update my logic that writes to the storage table.

Here's the relevant code.
**Http Trigger**

```
[FunctionName("Createwidget")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Createwidget(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "toys/widgets")] HttpRequest req,
         [Queue("widgets"), StorageAccount("ExtStorageQueue")] ICollector<string> messageQueue,
        ILogger log)
    {           
        widgetResponse response = new widgetResponse();
        var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        log.LogInformation($"Received following payload: {content}");

        var widgetRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<widget>(content);
        if (widgetRequest.name != null){     
                
                messageQueue.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(widgetRequest));  
                // this is where I need to update the code              
                response = await storage.ProvisioningRequest(widgetRequest, req.HttpContext.Items["MS_AzureFunctionsRequestID"].ToString(), "enqueued");                
        } 
        else {
            response.status = "Error: Invalid Request";
            response.requestId=null;
        }
        return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response));  
    }
```

This is a snippet from storage.ProvisioningRequest()

```
GetStorageAccountConnectionData
var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(
new Uri(connection.storageUri),
new TableSharedKeyCredential(connection.storageAccountName, connection.storageAccountKey));
var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(connection.tableName);
await tableClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

This is how I create the connection:

```
    private void GetStorageAccountManagedIDConnection()
    {
        var azureWebJobsStorage = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage");
        String[] accountDetailsArray = azureWebJobsStorage.Split(";");
        String[] accountNameArray = accountDetailsArray[1].Split("=");
        connection.storageAccountName = accountNameArray[1];

        var storageAccount= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ExtStorageQueue");
        String[] storageAccountDetailsArray = storageAccount.Split(";");
        String[] accountKeyDetailsArray = storageAccountDetailsArray[2].Split("AccountKey=");
        string storageKey = accountKeyDetailsArray[1];
        connection.tableName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("squeueTable");
        connection.storageUri = $"https://{connection.storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{connection.tableName}";
        connection.storageAccountKey = storageKey;
    }
```

Here's what my local.settings.json file looks like:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorageAccountName;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountKey=supersecretKey/asdf+asdf==",
    "squeueTable": "provisionedWidgets",
    "ExtStorageQueue__serviceUri": "https://mystorageAccountName.queue.core.windows.net",
   
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

is there a way to do this? I've been reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet#constructors and i don't see any constructors that allow me to use a managed id

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT 1**

Here's the simplified method that creates the connection config data:

```
    private void GetStorageAccountConnectionData()
    {
        //TODO:  remove hardcoded values and extract from local.settings.json instead.  For testing purposes only to see how serivceUri works.
        connection.storageAccountName = "mystorageaccountname";
        connection.tableName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageTableName");
        connection.storageTableUri = $"https://{connection.storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{connection.tableName}";
        connection.storageQueueUri = $"https://{connection.storageAccountName}.queue.core.windows.net/";
    }
```

and this is the logic that consumes it:

```
           GetStorageAccountConnectionData();
              var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(new Uri(connection.storageTableUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient(connection.tableName);
            TableEntity origEntity = tableClient.GetEntity<TableEntity>(
                                ENQUEUED_PARTITION,
                                notification.requestId);
```

No compile errors but the storage table is not written to.
I'm currently trying to see about creating debug messages / logs since I can't get my local debug environment working

**EDIT 2**

I finally got my local env set up so that I can debug.  So the logic that writes to my storage queue works but when I try to write to the storatge table, I can now see what the full error is.  This is the error:

```
Failed to create storage record:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.                                                                                                                                                                    ure.
RequestId:asdf-0002-asdf-6574-asdf
Time:2022-05-10T13:45:24.6319496Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Content:
{"odata.error":{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including 
is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:9f775fd8-0002-002c-6574-648209000000\nTime:2022-05-10T13:45:24.6319496Z"}}}

Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: asdf-asdf-asdf-asdf
x-ms-error-code: REDACTED
Date: Tue, 10 May 2022 13:45:23 GMT
Content-Length: 299
Content-Type: application/json
```

Also just to be explicit, the same behavior happens when I test in the cloud too.  So regardless of whether I call

```
 POST https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/widgets/workspaces
```

or

```
 POST http://localhost:7071/widgets/workspaces
```

it's the same behavior.  The storage queue is updated but not the table.

As far as the managed id is concerned, it now has the following permissions:

[image]

Comment: How about this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-ctor(system-uri-system-string-azure-core-tokencredential-azure-data-tables-tableclientoptions)?

Comment: @GauravMantri.  Cool!  I'll check it out

Comment: are you trying to create table or to access table ? to read/write to table you need different permissions: `Storage Table Data Contributor` or `Storage Table Data Reader`.

Comment: both.  but I have storage table data contributor role to the resource group, for the managed id.  I also have storage queue data contributor role to the the resource group ... and that one seems to be working.  I just added also to storage account level.  but ti's not working.

Comment: @Thomas please see edit 2

Comment: it can take few minutes for assignments to be proagated and you probably also need to log out / log in again

Comment: Also are you talking here about authenticating locally or using the managed identity, im getting confused.

Comment: @Thomas no problem.  The base question is about how to write to the storage table.  The answer you provided isn't working for me, but because I can't debug locally, I can't give you any useful info as why / what is failing.  All I see is that the table is NOT being populated upstream.  I have a separate question open about how to authenticate via vscode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244622/discussion-between-dot-and-thomas).

Comment: @Thomas, I got the local debug working.  Please see Edit 2 now for full error when I try to write to Storage Account using your sample code.  Please and thank yoU!

Comment: Did you manage to get the writing working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add a reference to these packages:

- [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity)
- [Azure.Data.Tables](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables)

You function app will need `Storage Account Contributor` or `Contributor` role at the storage level (Not sure to be honest).

Here is a snippet of how your code could looks like:

```
var serviceClient = new TableServiceClient(
  new Uri(connection.storageUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var tableClient = serviceClient.GetTableClient (connection.tableName);
await tableClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

Comment: k i'll try to test soon.  When I make the switch to use managed IDs, nothing works locally so have to figure that out first before I can test this. I'll post again soon.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using vs code / visual studio ? tou can login with your account in both case and make it work locally as well

Comment: I'm using vscode.  here's all the details in case it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72142747/azure-fn-local-debug-returns-error-defaultazurecredential-failed-to-retrieve

Comment: fwiw i also tried to simplify the connection logic just to use hardcoded values for now cuz I can't debug anything locally ... when I publish the fn upstream, the queue is written to using the managed id, but the table is failing.  I don't have any useful errors though.  I'll try to update the question here anyways with the code changes so the information is at least complete.

Comment: please see Edit 1 for latest code.

Comment: marking as answer because I think the root cause of issue is not related to the connection logic.  It's permissions issue now.  The only thing I thing I had to do to get this answer to work is to add my AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET to the local.settings.json file.  Then I was able to connect to the storage account.